# Finding every possible "non-duplicate" combination given a set of 6 digits

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, for-loop

So I was first asked to create a function to find ever possible combination given a set of 6 numbers that can range from 0-9 **EDIT** Keep in mind that the user is given a prompt for the input so the input can change or be different.. so in other words the input would be 123456 or 099384 **END EDIT**. This function would have to return every possible combination for a result of 3 digits while using the inputted 6 digits a repeatable amount of times.. So it would return like 111 112 113 etc..

. I'm a php/javascript user and opted for javascript so that it can be run in the browser on a offline file.

This is what I've built below which works well.

```
function findthree(nums) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (in_array(i, nums)) {
            for (var ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
                if (in_array(ii, nums)) {
                    for (var iii = 0; iii < 10; iii++) {
                        if (in_array(iii, nums)) {
                            $('body').append('<div>' + i + '' + ii + '' + iii + '</div>');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


function in_array(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**My Question Is**.. How would I create a similar function that shows every combination EXCEPT "combination duplicates". In other words, the function will not return 211 because 112 was already returned and 654 will not be returned because 456 would of already been returned. I was going to attempt to use a array_difference function but can not figure it out completely how that would work.

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT Answer found with help of the answer I selected

```
function findthreenodupe(nums) {
    nums = $.distinct(nums);
    nums.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b
    });
    alert(nums);
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (in_array(i, nums)) {
            for (var ii = i; ii < 10; ii++) {
                if (in_array(ii, nums)) {
                    for (var iii = ii; iii < 10; iii++) {
                        if (in_array(iii, nums)) {
                            $('body').append('<div>' + i + '' + ii + '' + iii + '</div>');
                        }
                    } // end of iii for loop
                } // end of ii for loop
            } // end of i for loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is your requirement, simply return only those combinations where all the digits are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is sort your input and remove duplicate digits. For example, from `099384` you get `03489`.

Then, you don't even have to check all the digits from `0-9`, and you can work directly with the array index. That will eliminate some work, and you can get rid of the ugly `if(in_array(i, nums))` brackets. Something like this should work:

```
for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    for(var ii=i; ii< nums.length; ii++){
        for(var iii=ii; iii<nums.length; iii++){
            $('body').append('<div>' + nums[i] + '' + nums[ii] + '' + nums[iii] + '</div>');
        }
    }
}
```

The key difference is not starting with the first index each time, but with the previous digit. This ensures each digit is `>=` to the one before it(since it's sorted), and it ends up resembling the handshake problem.

For the sample input above(revised to `03489`), you can visualize what it's doing below. Each run of the `iii` loop is a number. Each line is `ii` loop run, and each "block" is a run of the outer `i` loop.

```
000 003 004 008 009
033 034 038 039
044 048 049
088 089
099

333 334 338 339
344 348 349
388 389
399

444 448 449
488 489
499

888 889
899

999
```

Bonus: The *number* of combinations you'll find this way will always be the [tetrahedral number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number) for the number of distinct digits in `nums`.

Comment: The input ( array nums ) will always be changed. I edited post

Comment: To cope with that, preprocess your inputs. Sort them and remove duplicates. For your sample input `099384`, it would come out as `03489`. Then you can use the same `i<10` check you have, along with the `in_array` you have in the original. Just make sure you start each inner loop with the previous digit, not `1`.

Comment: this worked for me..thank you!! edited question to show answer

Comment: Actually.. what about numbers that have leading zeros? or zeros at all? since i starts at 1 it will not work. If I make it i=0 in the for loop will this work?

Comment: I updated with a more simplified version. If the inputs are sorted/distinct, you don't need `in_array()` at all, you can just iterate over the array itself, using the indices instead of `0-9`.

Comment: Also, you don't really need to edit the answer into the question. If an answer is good, just accepting/upvoting it is fine. If it's not *quite* good enough, but helped you on your way to the answer, you can write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following code would display the combination for 4,5,6. You can change to include what ever value

```
for (var i = 4; i < 7; i++)
    for(var y = i; y < 7 ; y++)
        for(var z = y ; z < 7; z++)
            $('#result').append('<div>' + i + '' + y + '' + z + '</div>');
```

IS this what you want. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ecaLf/)

Comment: That won't output any of the combinations involving 1, 2, or 3

Comment: like most other responses..this doesn't even use the nums array of input from the prompt.. the input could be 013328 ... won't always be 123456 etc..

Comment: Read the value from input array using the index !

Answer (score 0):

```
function findthree(nums) {
for (var i=0; in_array(i, nums); i++)
  if(in_array(i, nums))  
    for (var j=i; in_array(j, nums); j++) 
       if(in_array(j, nums) 
          for (var k=j; in_array(k, nums); k++)
             if(in_array(k, nums) {
               // other stuff
             }
```

If you don't want the results to include triplets which have the same digit more than once (112, 133, etc.), then change the initial values to not add the +1...

```
function findthree(nums) {
for (var i=0; in_array(i, nums); i++)
  if(in_array(i, nums))  
    for (var j=i+1; in_array(j, nums); j++) 
       if(in_array(j, nums) 
          for (var k=j+1; in_array(k, nums); k++)
             if(in_array(k, nums) {
               // other stuff
             }
```

Comment: does this even consider the input(nums)? I might not need every digit betwee 0-9 if the input is 111123

Comment: @jwpat7. typo, should have been lower case i. And I figured you could add the check for in the input array yourself... but I have edited to add that

Comment: OK i will try this example above